# Grafana fails to start server

Tags: service, grafana

I'm trying to install Grafana on a server, and installation goes through properly. However, when I try to start the service (using `sudo service grafana start`) it fails with the cryptic message:

```
2016/02/11 18:45:38 [web.go:93 StartServer()] [E] Fail to start server: open : no such file or directory
```

I have been unable to find an answer to this.

I assume that I'm simply missing an `apt-get` package or something really simple, but there's no more information than this.

Anyone have an idea?

Thanks for your time.

**EDIT:**
While unable to solve the actual problem, I realized that though I configured the server to run over HTTPS, the actual SSL is handled through the proxy by my host, and the server should run internally on HTTP. When changing this, the server started properly. It's not a solution to this specific problem, but as it may point others with this problem in the right direction;

*the problem had to do with running over HTTPS.*

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

when configuring Grafana to use HTTPs you need to specify cert & key paths, looks likely that Grafana could not find one of them.